# Red black tree delete function

Tags: c++, red-black-tree

The delete function doesn't work. If I delete a node, what remains is the subtree of the node.

What do you think is wrong with this?
Thanks in advance.

```
node *deleteNode(node* &root, node *z){
    node *x, *y;

        cout << "Element to delete: " << z->data << endl;
        if (z->leftchild == nil || z->rightchild == nil)
            y = z;
        else
            y = treesuccessor(z);

        if (y->leftchild != nil)
            x = y->leftchild;
        else
            x = y->rightchild;

        if (x != nil)
            x->parent = y->parent;

        if (y->parent == nil)
            root = x;

        else if (y == y->parent->leftchild)
            y->parent->leftchild = x;
        else
            y->parent->rightchild = x;


        if (y != z)
            z->data = y->data;
        if (y->color == black)
            deletefixup(root, x);
    return y;
}
```

Comment: You should tag the question with the language you are using. I don't think that `red-black-tree` is a popular tag, whereas `c` is.

Comment: Looks like a correct transcription from Introduction to Algorithms. :-) The problem must be elsewhere...